# There exists a constant $0 < q < 1$ (depending on $p$) such that $\mathbb{P}[X_1 + \ldots + X_n] < q^n$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be RVs such that
>
> $$ X_i = \begin{cases} 1 \quad &\text{ with probability } p \\ -1 \quad &\text{ with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that there exists a constant $0 < q < 1$ (depending on $p$) such that
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X_1 + \ldots + X_n \ge 0] < q^n$$
>
> for all $n$.

The setting reminds me of the Chernoff bound, which I learned in the following version:

> Chernoff's Bound: Let $X \sim Bin(n,p)$. Then for any $t > 0$ we have
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge \mathbb{E}[X]+t] \le e^{-\frac{t^2}{2(np+t/3)}}.$$

However, I do not see how this should be applicable here, since the $X_i$ are not Bernoulli distributed as they do not map into $\{0,1\}$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the exercise... what are we supposed to show?

Comment: Regarding the issue of Bernoulli-ness: note that $\frac{1}{2}(X_i + 1) \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$, so it might be possible to massage your probability into a form such that your version of Chernoff's bound is applicable. But as Andrew Zhang points out, there seems to be a typo in the problem statement.

Comment: $P[X_1 + \cdots + X_n]$? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, there was indeed a typo. I made an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Addendum: As Michael points out, I assume the $X_i$ are independent.*

Your version of Chernoff can be used here if $p < 1/2$.

Let $Y_i := \frac{1}{2}(X_i + 1)$. The probability can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + \cdots + X_n \ge 0)
&= P(Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n \ge n/2)
\\
&= P(Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n \ge np + (n/2-np))
\\
&\le \exp\left(-\frac{n^2 (1/2 - p)^2}{2n(p + (1/2-p)/3)}\right)
\\
&= q^n & q := \exp\left(-\frac{(1/2 - p)^2}{2(p + (1/2-p)/3)}\right)
\end{align}

For $p > 1/2$ I am not sure you can get a bound of that form. For instance if $p=1$, then the probability is $1$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming independence? If $X_i=X_1$ for all $i$ then $P[X_1+...+X_n\geq 0] = P[X_1\geq 0] = p$.

Comment: @Michael You're right. I'll edit my answer to mention this.